# css - how to stretch a background image across the entire window

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a background image I have when trying to stretch across the entire window. external CSS below:

```
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("mybackground.jpg"); -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 70%;}
@font-face /* support for browsers & IE v10 onwards*/
{
    font-family:homefont; src: url("font3.ttf");
}

#main
{
    position:absolute;
    left:450px;
    top:30px;
    font-family: homefont;
    font-size:150px;
    line-height:70%;
}
```

This is what I have (see white space to the right of the image on the browser window):

[image]

Can anyone advise me on how to stretch the image across the entire window?

I have tried the suggestions as advised in the comments, however - the image appears to be cut from my knees downward :(. Are there any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: remove `background-size: 70%;`   and add `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
background-size: 100%;
```

or

```
background-size:cover
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an axcellecnt article about your problem on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Awesome, Easy, Progressive CSS3 Way:

```
html {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

```
Safari 3+
Chrome
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)
```

Answer (score 0):

`top center;background-size-110%;background-repeat- no-repeat`

Please increase the size as you like.

Answer (score 0):

### Scale the background image to be as large as possible

You need to use the `background-size` property with the value `cover` like below

```
body {
      background-image: url("mybackground.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      background-size: cover;
      }
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)